# how to include two matches of multi-word regex that overlap with each other in python

Tags: regex, overlapping

I currently have a text as follows:

**for more cynicism and polarization in our politics  now there're no quick fixes to this long-term trend i agree our trade should be fair and not just free but the next wave of economic dislocations won't come from overseas it will come from the relentless pace of automation that makes a lot of good middle class jobs obsolete and so we're going to have to forge a new social compact to guarantee all our kids the**

so I would like to find matches that include 3 words both in front and behind the searched regex

The regex that I would like to search is `\b(com(es?|ing)|came)\b`

so the matches that I will be looking for will be

`economic dislocations won't come from overseas it`

and
`overseas it will come from the relentless`

so I've devised a regex that includes the specific rules
`\w+'?\w*\s\w+'?\w*\s\w+'?\w*\s\b(com(es?|ing)|came)\b\s\w+'?\w*\s\w+'?\w*\s\w+'?\w*`

but the two results overlap with each other and end up just with 1, which is the first match.

How do need to change my regex to include overlapping results?

Comment: You need a capturing group inside a positive lookahead, try `(?=\b((?:\w+(?:'\w*)*\s){3}(?:com(?:es?|ing)|came)(?:\s\w+(?:'\w*)*){3}))`. I guess `w*` is a typo and you wanted to write `\w*`

Comment: Yup Thks for pointing out. Ive included in a link where Im testing it out, and sadly the regex you've provided me seems to have couple of errors.. Can you plz take a look?
https://regex101.com/r/dBwoxZ/1

Comment: There are [no errors](https://regex101.com/r/dBwoxZ/2) with the regex, you have an error in the demo settings.

Comment: Oh you're right! Thks for your help :D
It works on python

Comment: Please check the code below, I also added the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure

- You use a word boundary before the first `\w` *and*
- Use a capturing group inside a positive lookahead

Besides, you can shorten the pattern if you use a non-capturing group quantified three times.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBwoxZ/2):

```
(?=\b((?:\w+(?:'\w*)*\s){3}(?:com(?:es?|ing)|came)(?:\s\w+(?:'\w*)*){3}))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EVPRbu):

```py
import re
text = r'''for more cynicism and polarization in our politics now there're no quick fixes to this long-term trend i agree our trade should be fair and not just free but the next wave of economic dislocations won't come from overseas it will come from the relentless pace of automation that makes a lot of good middle class jobs obsolete and so we're going to have to forge a new social compact to guarantee all our kids the'''
pattern = r"(?=\b((?:\w+(?:'\w*)*\s){3}(?:com(?:es?|ing)|came)(?:\s\w+(?:'\w*)*){3}))"
print( re.findall(pattern, text) )
```

Output:

```
["economic dislocations won't come from overseas it", 'overseas it will come from the relentless']
```